# How to record audio from specified device using C#?

Tags: c#, audio

How to record audio from specified device and convert it to byte array?
I tried to use CSCore, but it saves audio in file. I need just byte array

Answer (score 1):

I can help you there. Next time, tell us what you've already tried and why you're not getting anywhere.

I have translated my VB.NET code to C#. *Look for errors due to the conversion*.

Call `StartListening()` when you start your program, then `GetLatestData()` regularly.

`DataArray` is your desired byte array.

You still need to install `NAudio` in the Visual-studio nuget package manager.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars;

public class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     ''' sample rate of the soundcard in Hertz
    ///     ''' </summary>
    private int Samplerate = 48000;
    /// <summary>
    ///     ''' 1024
    ///     ''' Wenn mehr, kann man zwar auf 40 Hz testen, aber der Bildschirm wird zu selten aktualisiert.
    ///     ''' </summary>
    private readonly int BufferSize = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, 10)); // 1024

    private static NAudio.Wave.WaveIn wi = null;
    private NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider bwp = null;
    /// <summary>
    ///     ''' ≈22
    ///     ''' </summary>
    private double usedMilliseconds;
    private int cnt = 0;
    /// <summary>
    ///     ''' to hold the latest soundcard data which we will graph. <para></para>
    ///     ''' </summary>
    private double[] DataArray;


    private int how_many_bytes;

    private void AudioDataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        bwp.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        how_many_bytes = e.BytesRecorded;
    }

    private void Start_Listening()
    {
        wi = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
        wi.DeviceNumber = 1;
        wi.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(Samplerate, 16, 1);
        wi.BufferMilliseconds = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Convert.ToDouble(BufferSize) / System.Convert.ToDouble(Samplerate) * 1000.0);
        usedMilliseconds = System.Convert.ToDouble(BufferSize) / System.Convert.ToDouble(Samplerate) * 1000.0;
        wi.DataAvailable += AudioDataAvailable;
        bwp = new NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider(wi.WaveFormat);
        bwp.BufferLength = BufferSize * 2;
        bwp.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;

        try
        {
            wi.StartRecording();
        }
        catch (NAudio.MmException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, $"Could not record from audio device!{ControlChars.NewLine}{ControlChars.NewLine}{ex.Message}", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    public void getLatestData()
    {
        if (how_many_bytes == 0)
            return;

        byte[] audioBytes = new byte[how_many_bytes - 1 + 1];
        bwp.Read(audioBytes, 0, how_many_bytes);

        int bytesPerSample = 2;
        DataArray = (new double[how_many_bytes / bytesPerSample - 1 + 1]);

        for (int i = 0; i <= DataArray.Length - bytesPerSample; i += bytesPerSample)
            DataArray[i] = System.Convert.ToDouble(BitConverter.ToInt16(audioBytes, i * bytesPerSample));
    }
}
```